# Extremely slow file deletion on NFS drive

Tags: nfs, rm

I have a linux machine (OpenSuse), and there is a mount point on a network drive (NFS). In a folder containing log files (frequently modified), the file deletions (just the `rm` command) is extremely slow. It takes 5 seconds per file.

Note that this does not happen in every folder, while being on the same drive, same mounting point. It mostly happens in this folder containing logs (which however has nothing specific).

While capturing a `strace`, I noticed that the system call `unlinkat` was the bottleneck. It takes exactly 5 seconds more than expected. In the case below, it takes 5.002059 while you would expect 0.002059 seconds.

Any idea about the root cause ?

```
1092  17:59:32.923094 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "1.log", {st_dev=makedev(0, 35), st_ino=3476, st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_nlink=1, st_uid=2248, st_gid=2005, st_blksize=1048576, st_blocks=0, st_size=0, st_atime=2023/04/22-17:59:09, st_mtime=2023/04/22-17:59:09, st_ctime=2023/04/22-17:59:09}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0 <0.000291>
1092  17:59:32.923528 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "1.log", {st_dev=makedev(0, 35), st_ino=3476, st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_nlink=1, st_uid=2248, st_gid=2005, st_blksize=1048576, st_blocks=0, st_size=0, st_atime=2023/04/22-17:59:09, st_mtime=2023/04/22-17:59:09, st_ctime=2023/04/22-17:59:09}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0 <0.000083>
1092  17:59:32.923756 faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "1.log", W_OK) = 0 <0.000430>
1092  17:59:32.924345 unlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "1.log", 0) = 0 <5.002059>
```

Comment: Are those files huge? Is the number of files in that directory huge? Do you have shell access to the NFS server and can delete those files locally? Is that faster?